# How many times needed to Sort a number in an Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to count how many times needed for an array to be sorted

```
var array = [4,2,3,1]

var yourCounter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
 for (var j = 1; j < array.length-j; j++)
   if (array[j - 1] > array[j]) {
     yourCounter++;
   } }
```

it will return 4 , it should be 5

but if I input array [1,2,3] will correctly return 0 , and if I input array [3,2,1] it will correctly return 3

Comment: What do you mean by how many times to sort? Do you mean how many swaps are needed? In which case 4 is the correct answer

Comment: Why and how do you find `5` ?

Comment: For testCase2 in hackerank https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/ctci-bubble-sort/problem?h_l=interview&playlist_slugs%5B%5D%5B%5D=interview-preparation-kit&playlist_slugs%5B%5D%5B%5D=sorting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the given code and **swap the values** while counting.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
        // Swap adjacent elements if they are in decreasing order
        if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
            swap(a[j], a[j + 1]);
        }
    }
}
```

```js
var array = [4, 2, 3, 1],
    counter = 0,
    i, j, n = array.length;

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n - 1; j++) {
        if (array[j] > array[j + 1]) {
            [array[j + 1], array[j]] = [array[j], array[j + 1]];
            ++counter;
        }
    }
}

console.log(counter);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
var a = [4,2,3,1]

function sortArray(a){

let swapCount = 0;
let swapOccurred = true;
let index = 0;
while (swapOccurred == true && index < a.length){

    swapOccurred == false;

    if (a[index] > a[index+1]){
        let holder = a[index]
        a[index] = a[index+1];
        a[index+1] = holder;
        swapOccurred == true;
        swapCount ++;
        index = -1;
    }

    index ++
}

function countSwaps(a) {
    let swapCount = 0;

    [a, swapCount] = sortArray(a)

    console.log(swapCount)

}

    return [a, swapCount] 
}
```